# How to insert xml file into xml field using bcp?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, bcp

I have a table:

```
USE [testdb]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[a](
    [n] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [x] [xml] NULL)
GO
```

How to insert xml file into field x from client?
[MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184(v=sql.110).aspx) doesn't suit me.

```
    INSERT INTO T(XmlCol)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'c:\SampleFolder\SampleData3.txt',
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

I'm not the administrator of this server. And I have the only access to the database. I can not put a file in a directory on the server. I can use the BCP and other tools to access the database

XML file is very large (> 50 MB), so it doesn't turn to insert the text of file as a constant in the query SSMS

Comment: So, the question is how to insert a XML value in table's xml column using the BCP utility?

Comment: Explain please, *"I can't access the disk server"* and *"XML file is very large"*... You have a file but you can't acces it? Elaborate please. Give more context in your question (click `edit` link underneath your question and provide more context).

Comment: I'm not the administrator of this server. And I have the only access to the database. I can not put a file in a directory on the server. I can use the BCP and other tools to access the database

Comment: Sure, but *the bcp utility bulk copies data between an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and a data file in a user-specified format.* (from [BCP utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)). If you want to use BCP, the XML has to be in a file. Where would your file be located? Maybe you are looking at the wrong tool. From what environment do you want to store the XML file: a .NET program, a Java program, from a webpage, ... or is your environment really SQL Server?

Comment: I can write code c#, but need a "standard" tool. No need to parse the xml-file. I just need to put it in the field of table entirely.

Comment: What about loading the file within your C# application and fill the table column from there?

Comment: Of course, I can write something like this:
       `Using cnn As New SqlConnection(_cnnString)
            cnn.Open()
            Dim com As New SqlCommand("insert into dbo.a(x) values (@x)", cnn) With {.CommandType = CommandType.Text}
            com.Parameters.Add("@x", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)
            com.Parameters("@x").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            com.Parameters("@x").Value = IO.File.ReadAllText(_Path)
            com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using`
but I need a standard tool that can do the same. Maybe not the bcp.

Comment: @PeterJanvarev This is not a question of standard tool or bcp, it's a question of rights... If you need this tool and you seem to know how to do it, just write it yourself...

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the standard tool with this functionality - does not exist?

Comment: @PeterJanvarev Yes... The reason might be, that this is not a standard need... If you really want to build a standard tool to insert any kind of data into any structure you'd have to reinvent SSMS...

Answer (score 0):

Little known fact: the bcp utility supports [arbitrary strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx) as column and row delimiters.  Construct a file with delimiters not present in your data, and invoke bcp accordingly.

For example, your column delimiter could be `-t \0Field\0`.  Just check the data first.  :-)